# unorderered set for boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint - attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I am storing unique endpoints but getting compilation error for constructor

```cpp
std::unordered_set<boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint> addresses;
```

Error

```sh
Error C2280  'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
        with
        [
            _Kty=tcp_endpoint
        ]   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include\unordered_set
```

I tried to do it by defining comparer as below but I get run time assertion error saying invalid compare function.

```cpp
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
struct comp {
    bool operator()(const tcp::endpoint& l, const tcp::endpoint& r) const
    {
        if (l.address().to_string() != r.address().to_string()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
std::set<tcp::endpoint,comp> getSet() {
    std::set<tcp::endpoint, comp> setOfStrs;

    auto const address = net::ip::make_address("192.168.0.1");
    auto const port = 9090;
    tcp::endpoint ep{ address, port };

    auto const address2 = net::ip::make_address("192.168.0.2");
    auto const port2 = 9090;
    tcp::endpoint ep2{ address2, port2 };
    setOfStrs.insert(ep);
    setOfStrs.insert(ep2);

    setOfStrs.insert(ep2);

    return setOfStrs;
}
```

[image]

Please let me know how do I fix this. Its probably a small thing, but I am new to C++ so not able to figure it out soon.

In other languages one can use Hashset and call add to add an object.
I was using vector but there were duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `std::unordered_set` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) requires that the type you provide has two attributes:

- A hash function to determine the bucket in which one has to store the value
- A `operator==`, to see if two values are the same, in order to resolve collision

I can see from:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/endpoint.html

That `operator==` is available, but not the hash function. So you should write one yourself. Given that, for you it is OK to use also `std::set` I think you can use it directly it this way:

```
std::set<tcp::endpoint>
```

because `std::set` needs only a way to compare two elements (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and `endpoint` has `operator<`.

Alternatively, you should consider writing your own hash function and most likely your own comparator in order to fit your usecase, I see that you tried to use the output of `to_string()` of the `address` in your comparator. 
Maybe you can hash the output of `to_string()` to implement the hash function and use string comparison(on the output of `to_string()`) for the comparison function.

Comment: This may no longer be up to date since I see asio had a commit "
Add std::hash specialisations for ip::basic_endpoint<>. " for commit SHA 81c015003a.